# Viewing report in CRM 2011 hyperlinks don't work

Tags: reporting-services, dynamics-crm-2011

I have a RDL file containing a fairly simple report, which in turn has to be deployed to CRM 2011.

The report itself works perfectly, showing data as expected; it's supposed to work **on-Premise only**, so it leverages direct SQL access to Filtered Views in order to fetch data.

When I tried to insert hyperlinks aiming to let users quickly open records, I found out that they apparently work as they are supposed to when I preview the report, but upon deployment on CRM they are being stripped of the "active" part, and all I'm left with is a colored line of text. I receive no errors and the report itself keeps working *perfectly*.

I referenced this link to build the "active" text -> [CRM report drill-through action](http://www.powerobjects.com/blog/2011/12/01/microsoft-dynamics-crm-report-drill-thru-action-to-crm-record/), basically leveragin the "Action" property of a textbox, and the `CRM_URL` parameter, like this:

*This goes inside Text Box properties -> Action -> "Go to URL"*

```
=Iif(IsNothing(Parameters!CRM_URL.Value), 
    "", 
    Parameters!CRM_URL.Value + 
        "?ID={" + Fields!id.Value.ToString() + 
        "}&LogicalName=myEntitySchemaName")
```

I tried scavenging Google but it feels like either no one did encounter the same problem or the solution is so trivial no one wrote anything about it.

Anyone had this problem before and knows how to face it ?

**UPDATE** *After having fiddled more with the code*

The expression I'm trying to use as "go to url" action is actually **evaluated correctly**. If I copy-paste it as content expression for the textbox I can see the full URL (which, in turn, when copy-pasted in a browser *opens the record as expected*).

Another (maybe not) useful information to add is that our environment is running **CRM 2011 UR3**

Comment: The last bit of your comment feels like it's very related. What happens if you place just `Fields!id.Value` as the Text of the TextBox? Does it output the ID you expect?

Comment: Yikes, that's one weird problem then. You should consider adding that last comment to the question by editing it, that's quite relevant info. I'm sorry though I don't have an answer for you.

Comment: I've cleaned up my own comments and updated the question

Answer (score 5):

I had this exact same issue. To resolve place the URL in Action | Go To URL on the **PLACEHOLDER** control not the textbox.

I found if I used the textbox, the custom report would preview fine in Visual Studio and Reporting Services, but as soon as I uploaded the RDL to CRM the URL would silently get ignored.

Placing the URL on the placeholder fixes this (well for me it did).

Answer (score 2):

Your expression looks correct.  Did you put the URL on the Textbox Property's "Action"?  It can be tricky to get to the correct context menu, so make sure nothing in the Tablix is selected and then Right-Click on the Text Box.

[image: right-click]
[image: action property]

Comment: It looks like you have this part correct.  Did you try removing the IIf?

Comment: Removing the Iif doesn't change anything, unfortunately. I triple-checked and I'm positive I've put the expression in the correct "Action"->"Go To URL" location (I even tried with a lonely textbox to ensure the tablix wasn't in the way)

Comment: Is the Action inserting a hyperlink?  Can you hard-code the Action on that or another Textbox to google?

Comment: I'm positive about the expression generating the right URL because if I use it as expression for the value of the textbox it shows perfectly formed URLs (which work, if I copy-paste them in a browser)

Comment: I agree, your expression looks fine.  I was just wondering if there is something strange in your report that prevents even a hard-coded action from creating a hyperlink.  Can you get *any* Textboxes to show as a hyperlink?